# Create a variadic method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uicolor

I want to make a variadic method to accept any number of textfields and a UIColor as inputs and my intention is to add a bottom line of that specific color to all thus textfields inside method.

How can I make such a method in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this would do:

```
func applyColour(toTextfields textfields: UITextField..., colour: UIColor) {
    for textfield in textfields {
        // Apply the colour here.
    }
}
```

Comment: From the Swift Documentation:

The values passed to a variadic parameter are made available within the function’s body as an array of the appropriate type. For example, a variadic parameter with a name of numbers and a type of Double... is made available within the function’s body as a constant array called numbers of type [Double].

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
 Common.addBottonLine(color: UIColor.white, userNameTextField, passwordTextField)
```

Method definition

```
 class func addBottonLine(color: UIColor, _ txtFields: UITextField... ) -> Void {

    for textF in txtFields {

        var bottomLine = CALayer()

        bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: textF.frame.height - 2) , size: CGSize.init(width: textF.frame.width, height: 2 ))

        bottomLine.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        textF.borderStyle = .none
        textF.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this function to add bottom line**

```
func addBottomLabel(_ color: UIColor) {
let lbl1 = UILabel()
lbl1.backgroundColor = color
addSubview(lbl1)
addVisualConstraints(["H:|[label]|", "V:[label(1)]|"], forSubviews: ["label": lbl1])
 }
```

Use :

```
let textFields = [your textfield array]
for textFields in textFields
{  
textFields.addBottomLabel(.yourcolor)
}
```